Get route within azure function and python
I'm searching for a way to get the route of my azure-function from the app or req object. I assume this should be straight forward. But I'm not able to find it.
 import azure.functions as func
 
 app = func.Function(...)
 
 app.route(route="myfunction")
 def my_function(req: func.Httprequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    route = ??    # should be myfunction

Does any one know how to get the route?
Edit
When I inspect the route_params of req in debugg mode I see this:
  req.route_params.values()
  > dict_values([])
  req.route_params.keys()
  > dict_keys([])


You can use this route = req.url.split('/')[-1]    https://i.imgur.com/4iwYWqO.png, https://i.imgur.com/B2CISHd.png

The split url works and I will check how it behaves with route parameters. Maybe I neet to circle back to the app.get_functions()[0].get_bindings()[0].route approach.


Get route within azure function and python

You can use below code:
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="rithwik")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Hello!!')
    rith = req.url.split('/')[-1] 
    logging.info(f"Route: {rith}")
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, route value is {rith}.")

Output:


If there is many / in route then you can use code like below:
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from urllib.parse import urlparse

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="rithwik/r")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Hello!!')
    x = urlparse(req.url)
    rith =x.path.split('/api/', 1)[-1]
    logging.info(f"Route: {rith}")
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, route value is {rith}.")

Output:


